# A rest parameter must be of an array type when passing tuple type

Tags: typescript

I have a type that determines whether a type is a tuple (exact length) or an array. I want to be able to use this condition to infer the type of a parameter:

```
type ANumber = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10;

type IsTuple<Type> = Type extends readonly unknown[] ? Type['length'] extends ANumber ? true : false : false;

function fn<T extends Record<keyof T, unknown>>() {
  return function withConfig(config: {
    [K in keyof T]: IsTuple<T[K]> extends true
      ? (...params: T[K]) => void
      : (param: T[K]) => void
  }) {};
}

fn<{ tupleType: [number, number], arrayType: number[] }>()({
  tupleType: (one, two) => {},
  arrayType: (arr) => {}
})
```

The actual function call works fine, `one`, `two`, and `arr` are all inferred correctly. However, `? (...params: T[K]) => void` errors with:

```
A rest parameter must be of an array type
```

Yet...a tuple *is* an array type isn't it? How do I point the compiler in the right direction here?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKjUF4oG0B2BXAtgIwgJwBooMd8BdAbgFgAoUSKAQXiRNz2UttvukYDks7RFAAMUAD5QAjJKgAmOQGY5AFjkBWOQDY5AdjkAOOQE4500dRo9w0AJIBnGOjAAbCAB4YtgHwjvDBAAHsAQqAAmDlB4EACG4QD2qK4gUOioANaoCQDuqJxQAPywtsgA5O6oAObAABZlZFDBoRFRAkL4RVDAeOjQAFxQAGaxrg4Dw6PjVjYMMCpIjs5unnA%20Vryw6otOLu4ezOvcNEPpAMbAAJZJw6heTSFhkVAAShBnCXjhHhkQIAlDWBEdJZXKoHw%20AAUAEooABvWhQaIQYDoPCoYbnK43HKXOoAYSSQ0uVUhH1QxKqgwRNCRSOQAGkoJcMb9-oCYGRBks9qtGWQ-M0nlEen1EXSkcVIQA6WVgWJ4WKYByDGD82EIPwANwSl3C4olg0h8sVmFV6sQ2t1%20tpUAAvrC4XarHbjkM7nDuryAhBBmgOoRiAGyEQFYqQD7Bmx8AU7VDoZCaUjUStI1BIUkIERgDkEhq-E6COKw7EI7YjWH8-DXTQHUA)

Comment: [Consider checking if `T[K]` is an array first.](https://tsplay.dev/WJX5RN)

Comment: @caTS In your example, `arr` is typed as `number`, not `number[]`.

Comment: I feel like `number extends T['length']` is probably a better check for non-tuples (or at least for non-closed-ended tuples) than what you're doing.  You could write [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2z34w) for brevity.  Still, if I were pressing ahead with your approach, I'd just accept that there's no such thing as a "type alias type guard" to tell the compiler that `IsTuple<T> extends true` has any implication for `T` and just use `Extract` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NB5Rkw).  Does that address your question fully or am I missing something?

Comment: Right... I got to a [similar conclusion](https://tsplay.dev/mbQnBN). I don't quite know how I came up with the first :p

Comment: @jcalz I don't think your first solution quite works. See this example: https://tsplay.dev/mppLpm - it's wrapping function parameters in `[]`. Your second solution does work, however, so if you write it up, I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: That's a separate issue and a correct error (I'm not sure why passing in a single argument where a spread is expected would work; you'd want `f(...x)` and not `f(x)` if `x` is an arg tuple) and I'd fix it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOARlm).  But it's out of scope of the question as asked.  I'm happy to write up the second solution as a direct answer to the question as asked, but for your sake I hope you'll change the code to something more tractable.  Anyway I'll get to it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you come upon a situation where you have a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `XXX` that *you* know is or will be assignable to type `YYY` but the *compiler* does not (and there is an error because of it), you can often work around the situation by replacing `XXX` with `Extract<XXX, YYY>` using [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union).

The compiler is able to understand that `Extract<XXX, YYY>` is assignable to both `XXX` and `YYY`.  Later, when the generic type is specified, then `Extract<XXX, YYY>` will be exactly the same as whatever `XXX` resolves to, *assuming you were correct about `XXX` being assignable to `YYY` in the first place*.

In your example, you have `T[K]` and you know it is assignable to an array type like `readonly unknown[]` but the compiler does not know this.  (It doesn't perform the sort of higher-order type analysis to see that `IsTuple<T>` is defined in such a way that `IsTuple<T> extends true` implies that `T` is an array type.)  So you can replace `T[K]` with `Extract<T[K], readonly unknown[]>`:

```
function fn<T extends Record<keyof T, unknown>>() {
  return function withConfig(config: {
    [K in keyof T]: IsTuple<T[K]> extends true
    ? (...params: Extract<T[K], readonly unknown[]>) => void  // okay
    : (param: T[K]) => void
  }) { };
}
```

That works, and the rest of your code should work more or less the same way as it did before.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKjUF4oG0B2BXAtgIwgJwBooMd8BdAbgFgAoUSKAQXiRNz2UttvukYDks7RFAAMUAD5QAjJKgAmOQGY5AFjkBWOQDY5AdjkAOOQE4500dRo9w0AJIBnGOjAAbCAB4YtgHwjvDBAAHsAQqAAmDlB4EACG4QD2qK4gUOioANaoCQDuqJxQAPywtsgA5O6oAObAABZlZFDBoRFRAkL4RVDAeOjQAFxQAGaxrg4Dw6PjVjYMMCpIjs5unnA+Vryw6otOLu4ezOvcNEPpAMbAAJZJw6heTSFhkVAAShBnCXjhHhkQIAlDWBEdJZXKoHw+AAUAEooABvWhQaIQYDoPCoYbnK43HKXOoAYSSQ0uVUhH1QxKqgwRNCRSOQAGkoJcMb9-oCYGRBks9qtGWQ-M0nlEen1EXTipCAHQysCxPCxTAOQYAURCCouXn5RBi8SSKTSmWyeU4PlhCD8ADcEpdwuKkYNIXKFZhBjB+earTa7bSoABfWFw-1WP3HIZ3IOolYBCCDNAdQjEBNkIjyhUgGODNj4Ap+qHQyE0pFR9yZqCQpIQIjAHIJT3w-0EcVp2IZ2yOtP1oOhmgB46oRUQBxys7QABCKNCeHh4s2AAUvH4kPAha1kXrkqlYqgQAVitnp6vnu6KmEavVGsVkJyoG7byhOTNfadUBdrhjw-cj1E3h8vj8-gBIFDVBPIIRhGdfSRGJUXRTFX2xDFcQJIkSTJVCqUguk6UZZlWUAjkuXLGUpWdRVlSgBd3QZAV62tW17X9QNGOglE0Q-LF3ygAEGT+DwmW-KA2SAmAoTZQYGWYqDsORWCMXJSlkDZMhpRlSFkDhP1GliKIqP5M1oSsGT-UYv0jJM6xnwjbpeTLeNSETA8UygFs20gLME04IgEjARDRjLA85Ho8J-XzQtGJLCAywrVAq26Wsu0bRjXOiztED8bsm2kny-NcaKyMwRKeyRPteyAA)